# How to use MySQL in static function in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

when write the following code in a static function, got need non-static error

**An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property**

is it possible to wrap something which can not write in static function to make it that can be written in static function?

can not compile
i use example code

```
 private static bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }catch(Exception ex) {}
    }
```

Comment: Too little context, add the full code of the static method

Comment: Show the complete block. Its hard to say what you're after. Surely you can add that to any static method.

Comment: Probably because query and connection are not static

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code as posted, nor with using MySql in a static method. You need to provide more information. What is `query` and `connection`? Are those non-static members?

Comment: Provide exception details please.. far too vague.

Comment: updated question, it can not compile if using in static function

Comment: Because `connection` is a non-static member. Either make `OpenConnection` non-static, or change `connection` to being static (not recommended), or provide some way for your static method to obtain a connection from a static member (method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access a non static member from a static function. Non static members are tied to an instance of the class, while static members are tied to the class itself.

Your options are:

```
static IDbConnection connection; //<- note the static keyword
private static bool OpenConnection()
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        return true;
    }catch(Exception ex) {}
}
```

That's a really bad approach anyway.

Otherwise make the whole thing non static:

```
IDbConnection connection; //<- now its an instance member.
private bool OpenConnection()
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        return true;
    }catch(Exception ex) {}
}
```

May be you should pass the right instance of connection object to open it. Something like:

```
private static bool OpenConnection(IDbConnection connection)
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        return true;
    }catch(Exception ex) {}
}
```

Now you can just call `Class.OpenConnection(someConnection);`

Maintaining a single instance of connection object is not a good idea. Each time you want it, just create a new instance, open the connection, query, and dispose off. Without seeing more context, its hard to give a definite answer as to what you *really* want. A blind guess to a better solution for your problem:

```
private static IDbConnection GetConnection()
{
    try
    {
        var connection = new WhateverConnection(yourConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
        return connection;
    }catch(Exception ex) {}
}
```

Run query using the connection object, and dispose it off from there.